# Deploy web application on client server(IIS)?

Tags: iis, deployment

I want to know whether is it possible to deploy some web application on client machine using some installer.
Explanation:-
Suppose i have one web application which my client wants to deploy on there server. So can i create any windows application  which will download all the required files and folder on client server and deploy that application on to the client Internet Information Services . If it is possible please explain me how can i achieve this.

Thanks
Yogesh Pawar